# Element Tree doesn't load a Google Earth-exported KML

Tags: python, xml, kml, elementtree

I have a problem related to a Google Earth exported KML, as it doesn't seem to work well with Element Tree. I don't have a clue where the problem might lie, so I will explain how I do everything.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    kmlFile = open( filePath, 'r' ).read( -1 ) # read the whole file as text
    kmlFile = kmlFile.replace( 'gx:', 'gx' )   # we need this as otherwise the Element Tree parser
                                               # will give an error

    kmlData = ET.fromstring( kmlFile )
    document = kmlData.find( 'Document' )
```

With this code, ET (Element Tree object) *creates* an Element object accessible via variable kmlData. It points to the root element ('kml' tag). However, when I run a search for the sub-element 'Document', it returns None. Although the 'Document' tag is present in the KML file!

Are there any other discrepancies between KMLs and XMLs apart from the 'gx: smth' tags? I have searched through the KML files I am dealing with and found nothing suspicious. Here is a simplified structure of an KML file the program is supposed to deal with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
   <name>UK.kmz</name>
   <Style id="sh_blu-blank">
    <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.3</scale>
        <Icon>
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-blank.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x="32" y="1" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
    </IconStyle>
    <ListStyle>
        <ItemIcon>
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-blank-lv.png</href>
        </ItemIcon>
    </ListStyle>
  </Style>
    [other style tags...]
  <Folder>
    <name>UK</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name>1262 Crossness Pumping Station</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>0.1329926667038817</longitude>
            <latitude>51.50303535104574</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <range>4246.539753518848</range>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <heading>-4.295161152207489</heading>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#msn_blu-blank15000</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>0.1389579668507301,51.50888923518947,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
         [other placemark tags...]
  </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Do you have an idea why I can't access any sub-elements of 'kml'? By the way, Python version is 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KML document is in the `http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2` namespace, as indicated by

```
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
```

This means that the name of the `Document` element is in fact `{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2}Document`.

Instead of this:

```
document = kmlData.find('Document')
```

you need this:

```
document = kmlData.find('{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2}Document')
```

However, there is a problem with the XML file. There is an element called `gx:altitudeMode`. The `gx` bit is a namespace prefix. Such a prefix needs to be declared, but the declaration is missing.

You have worked around the problem by simply replacing `gx:` with `gx`. But the proper way to do this would be to add the namespace declaration. Based on https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/altitudemode, I take it that `gx` is associated with the `http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2` namespace. So for the document to be well-formed, the root element start tag should read

```
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
```

Now the document can be parsed:

```
In [1]: from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

In [2]: kmlData = ET.parse("kml2.xml")

In [3]: document = kmlData.find('{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2}Document')

In [4]: document
Out[4]: <Element '{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2}Document' at 0x1895810>

In [5]:
```

Comment: The question was silly, as I am not familiar with XML very much. I have explored namespaces a little bit, and something similar to what you have said worked... However, I later decided to simply remove anything having to do with namespaces from XMLs prior to dealing with them, as the data I need to extract is pretty simple and not under any weird namespace."Proper" way of solving the issue is just not worth the effort in my case, I'd say... But thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If you ever should want to explore XML namespaces more, this might be useful: http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm. The official ElementTree documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) does not say much about this subject.